# Facebook Tag Code in Message from FacebookClient posting is not working

Tags: c#, facebook

Can we add facebook tag-code (@[PAGEID:0]) in message during posting on facebook page using c#.
I am using FacebookClient in C# and trying to add tag code.i tries in different way what i found on google and facebook reference pages.(@[pageid:0] and @@[0:[pageid:0:pagedisplayname]])
like this

```
@@[0:[mypageid:0:StreetDance]]
```

But its not working..